# ServiceNow: dynamically create table from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table, servicenow

I'm  trying to create a widget in ServiceNow that displays all the knowledge articles that is relevant to a user based on their location and occupation.  There are cases where multiple KA articles should return and I want to dynamically create a table that lists out all of the articles that apply.  Below is my server script where I retrieve the user's occupation and location from HR_Profile.  Then, I open an empty array where I loop through each knowledge article that fits the filters, grab the KA number and short description, and then push it into my empty array:

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('hr_profile');
    gr.addQuery('user', gs.getUserID());
    gr.query();
    if(gr.next())
    {
  var occ = gr.occupation;
  var loc = gr.user.location;
  }

var kaArray = [];
var ka = new GlideRecord('x_81991_knowledge');
     ka.addQuery('workflow_state', 'Published');
     ka.addQuery('kb_category.label', 'Benefits');
     var qc1 = ka.addQuery('occupation', 'CONTAINS', occ);
     qc1.addOrCondition('location', 'CONTAINS', loc);
     ka.orderByDesc('sys_updated_on');
     ka.query();
     while(ka.next()) {
            obj = {number: ka.number,
            short_desc: ka.short_description,
             url: 'kb_view.do?sysparm_article=' + ka.number}
   kaArray.push(obj);
  }
```

My problem is how do I access the array and loop through to create an HTML table with three columns (number, description, URL) and all the articles associated with that individual?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this seems highly similar to the previous post you've made on StackOverflow. I assume they're related. Just so you know, this contextual information, if provided on that post, may have made it so I could've provided just one, more complete answer to help you out a bit better.

What you need to do to make a widget do what you're looking for, is a `<div>` tag in the HTML of your widget, with `ng-repeat` attribute. In your server-side code, you need to use the `data` object to populate your widget's columns, as you can see in a myriad of widgets which contain existing examples of tables being rendered using Angular. 
(You could also use `<table>`, and just have your column tags repeat. There are really a myriad of other ways to do it).

Here is one widget which is probably very very close to what you're looking to accomplish, you just need to tweak it a bit (which you can do partially, using the code I provided in answer to your other question):

https://**your_instance**.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=sp_widget.do?sys_id=3c817b52cb30020000f8d856634c9cfb

(This assumes you're on Istanbul, possibly Helsinki).